# Add pagination to div of rails form

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, pagination

I have a section of a rails form (_form.html.erb).

```
<div class= "form-group" style="overflow-y auto; height: 200px;">
  <p><strong>Associated Things </strong></p>
  <% for thing in Thing.All %>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag "bigthings[thing_ids][]", thing.id, @bigthings.things.include?(thing) %>
      <%= thing.name %>
    </div>
  <%end%>
</div>
```

I want to add a pagination to this checkbox this so my users wouldn't have to stroll through a long list of things.

Comment: Megan, was my post helpful? Was that what you were looking for? Let me know. I think using a custom action (with the controller code I mentioned) and the remote option on view helper is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a gem like [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) or [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate). For instance, using the first I mentioned, you should change your controller action and put this code:

```
@things = Thing.order(:order_col).page params[:page]
```

Then in the view you do:

```
<% for thing in @things %>
...
<%end%>
<%= paginate @things %>
```

Comment: Would this work even on if the above code is on the form_for @bigthing?

Comment: Well, the code I mentioned hits the server each time you press on a page number link (the helper method `<%= paginate @things %>` will print the available pages given @things size) - if that bothers your form then you can use the ajax way of the helper method which is `<%= paginate @things, :remote => true %>`

Comment: Additionally you can set the action where you have the controller code for the refresh of pages using another parameter on the helper: `<%= paginate @things, :remote => true, :params => {:controller => 'foo', :action => 'bar'} %>`.